# Pygame - keyboard input bug - multiple times print on screen

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to display the keyboard input on the screen using python3 but here's some issues with the code.

1. If I type rapidly, the letters get repeated. For example: If I type in `zo` quickly, the screen output is `zozz` but if I type slowly, it outputs `zo`
2. The shift key isn't working as expected. For example: If I press Left (or right) shift and `z`, it outputs `Z` but after I release Left shift and type `z`, it still outputs `Z` and the next time when I press `z` it outputs `z`. I don't know why this happening because I reset the `shift` flag at the end to `0`
3. The capslock key isn't working as expected either. Once I press capslock, the output is all uppercase but when I press it again, the output does go into lowercase, it remains uppercase. I know here that the `capsLock` flag isn't working but I'm not able to debug it.

Any ideas on how to get past these issues?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

def getch_mod():

    inputStr = ''
    shift = 0
    capsLock = 0
    a = 30

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Key Press Test")
    f1=pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",24)

    while True:
        events = list(pygame.event.get())
        for ev in events:
            screen.fill((255,255,255))
            text = f1.render('Enter password:', True, (0,0,0))
            screen.blit(text,(10,10))

            text = f1.render(inputStr, True, (0,0,0))
            screen.blit(text, (100,a))

            if (ev.type == pygame.QUIT):
                return

            if pygame.key.get_focused():    
                press = pygame.key.get_pressed()    
                for i in range(0,len(press)):
                    if (press[i] == 1):    
                        name = pygame.key.name(i)    
                        if (name == 'left shift' or name == 'right shift'):
                            shift = 1
                            break  
                        if (name == 'caps lock'):
                            if (not capsLock):
                                capsLock = 1
                            else:
                                capsLock = 0
                            break

                        if (name != 'return' and name != 'left shift' and name != 'right shift' and name != 'caps lock'):
                            if (shift or capsLock):
                                name = name.upper()
                            inputStr += str(name)
                            shift = 0
        pygame.display.update()

c = getch_mod()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very complex for what you're trying to do.

All you have to do is iterate over the event list and add the characters unicode representation to the string. Avoid calling `pygame.key.get_pressed()` since it doesn't take the order of the key press into account.

Also, don't have your logic in the event loop unless it's acting on a single event. Currently you're blitting the text for every event that happen, instead of for every frame.

Having `pygame.key.get_focused` in the event loop is unnecessary, since if a key event has been put in the event loop then the window have to have user focus.

Here's a short example on how to blit key input:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 720))

input_str = ''
comic_sans_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 24)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            input_str += event.unicode

    text = comic_sans_font.render(input_str, True, (0, 0, 0))

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text, (100, 200))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed now. Thanks Ted for the short and simple code and for the extra information on pygame. I need to make myself more comfortable with pygame and its libraries/functions

Comment: No need for embarrassment. It can be hard to know about these things at first.